WPF ListView - Scroll does not work when the mouse is on an item in listview
I have a list view control containing user control in WPF project.
As I stated in the title the scrolling does not work when the mouse is on item(user control) in listview.
How can i allow scrolling when the mouse cursor on item ?
One way to do this is to make IsEnabled property of items turns to false. But i don't want to disable items.
Here is xaml code of listview:
 <ListView Name="ListViewProducts"
               Margin="0,40,0,0"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
               Background="Transparent"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}" >
    
    
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>

                 <StackPanel Height="250">
                     <Border Height="220"
                             Width="300"
                              Margin="0">
                         <Border.Effect>
                             <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5"
                                               Opacity="0.5"
                                               Color="#FF2973EC"/>
                         </Border.Effect>
                         <Grid>
                             <uc:StationUC/>
                             
                         </Grid>
                     </Border>

                 </StackPanel>

             </DataTemplate>
             
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <ListView.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <WrapPanel/>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemsPanel>
     </ListView>



Most likely, everything in the visual tree of the child element has an element that intercepts the scrolling of the wheel. Usually this is ScrollViewer. You need to look at the StationUC layout. However, it will not necessarily be explicit there. It may be part of the template of some element that you included in the layout. To accurately pinpoint the problem, you may need to look at the dynamic visual tree while debugging.
